# Reference Field Value In Function

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I have generated a Tabulator table via JavaScript. I have a column that is displaying a download icon and has a `cellClick` event. In the `cellClick` event I am calling a custom function and wish to pass the function the value of a field that is displayed in another column. I'm having difficulty determining how to reference the field value in the other column to pass to my function.

The column with the download icon is coded as:

Note: the downloadIcon is being generated with a function to display a Font Awesome icon.

```js
{formatter: downloadIcon, width: 50, align: 'center', cellClick:function(e, cell){fileDownload(pdfURI);}}
```

The ***pdfURI*** that I wish to pass to the `fileDownload` function is a field in my table and is displayed in another column.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the ***getData*** function on the [Cell Component](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/components#component-cell) passed into the click callback, This will return the data object for the row.

```js
{formatter: downloadIcon, width: 50, align: 'center', cellClick:function(e, cell){
    fileDownload(cell.getData().pdfURI);
}}
```